# How Can I Get The Web-Loaded HTML of The Current Page in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a page where I must login to get the page I would like to scrape using BeautifulSoup. My code currently looks like

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox();
//loginpage is the page where I have to login. It is just used as a placeholder for this question
driver.get("loginpage");
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("username");
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("password");
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"return validateFields();\"]").click();
//contentpage is where I get the content to scrape from. It is also just used as a placeholder for this question.
driver.get("contentpage");
html = driver.page_source;
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml");
status = soup.find_all("span");
for status in status:
    print(status);
```

But I think that the HTML is the wrong page because BeautifulSoup is returning NoneType when I can look in the browser and see that it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Once you invoke *`get()`* and before you extract the `page_source` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) of any of the ***visible*** element and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("contentpage")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_of_a-visible_element")))
html = driver.page_source
```

As an alternative, you can also use *`document.documentElement.outerHTML`* as follows:

```
driver.get("contentpage")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_of_a-visible_element")))
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to retrieve html source from the web application WindGuru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993001/how-to-retrieve-html-source-from-the-web-application-windguru/53006894#53006894)
- [How to get the html in selenium of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140839/how-to-get-the-html-in-selenium-of-current-page/70143124#70143124)